# How to check responsive UI on mobiles?

Tags: android, ios

i'm working on PC -windows 10 and i'm looking for a software to check different screen resolutions for testing a website's responsive UI .I'm currently working with  Chrome's  debugger but i wonder which tools do you guys using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following techniques:

1) developer console has responsive tool.

2) resize your browser

3) host it temporarily using ngrok and open that link in your mobile browsers.

4) there are many online tools also which will help you to see responsiveness' by selecting type of device.

Comment: I have given according to priority. Till 3rd are the best options.